# Can you compile sass on github?

Tags: github, sass

My team use GitHub for version control, not Git. We all use GitHub Desktop for Mac.

I am introducing them to Sass, but want to compile on commit, is this possible?

Thanks,
Lisa

Comment: I am not quite sure what it is you are trying to achieve

Comment: Can you use GitHub for Desktop to compile Sass on commit? Or suggest a plugin for it that can?

Comment: You cannot compile Sass on commit using `GitHub for Desktop`. As for plugins, I do not know of any but someone else might be able to help you out with that. You could however look into a custom script using the command line/ terminal that both compiles and commits. I would suggest compiling prior to commit in case there is a compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

There is simply no definite way of compiling sass through github desktop. It uses git to push, pull etc. and git can't compile your sass.

Besides that, I don't see any use case of only compiling on pushing to github. If you want to only have the css files (the compiled sass) on the github repo you should add the folder of your sass file to your `.gitignore` and make use of a script/tool that will compile the sass while you're coding it. (the way I use sass and, as far as I know, everyone does.)

There are plenty of script and tools that can do this for you. I can't really recommend any right now as I don't know your programming languague nor your operating system tho.